Boy under barmitzvah leading Kabbalat Shabbat
A number of shuls grapple with the question of how to involve children in tefillah. In orthodox shuls I regularly see boys (even under barmitzvah) reciting Anim Zemirot (this is common). I have seen children lead pesukei d'zimra on shabbat in sephardi minyanim, where they tend to recite paragraphs out loud and the children, as a result, have a good grasp of דיוק מילים. I have also seen children leading אין כאלוהינו at the end of Shabbat shacharit.
What are the halachic grounds for allowing boys under the age of barmitzvah to lead Kabbalat Shabbat?

I'm confused as to what exactly your question is. Isn't it pretty clear from the linked article? "Leading" kabbalat shabbat is halachically meaningless. Therefore there is no issue for a minor to do so. And in theory, a woman could also, were we not to worry that allowing this would lead to women serving as the chazzan for arvit.

I didn't downvote but am also confused as to the second para. If. you ask about children, why bring women into the equation. Children and women are a very different set of issues. Could you clarify what you are asking about?

A local Sephardic shul always has a child lead kabbalas Shabbos. I find it very beautiful.

R. Dov Lior addresses the following question:

שאלה: האם ניתן למנות שליח ציבור נער בן עשר לתפילת קבלת שבת בלבד שהנוסח
וכוונת התפילה ידועים לו היטב והוא מאד מעוניין בכך, לפי מנהגי אשכנז?
תשובה: אפשר, מפני שאינו מוציא אף אחד מהמתפללים ידי חובה וכל אחד אוצר
בפני עצמו את פרקי התהילים האלה. אבל בקביעות אל תעשו כך, אלא אם יש צורך
בזה.
Question: According to Ashkenazi custom may one appoint as a prayer leader a child that is ten years
old for Qabalath Shabbath, provided that he knows the prayers well and
their intentions, and is interested in doing so?
Answer: It is possible, since none of the other worshipers have any
obligations fulfilled through him and they all are all a "treasure
unto themselves" that know these chapters of Psalms. However to
appoint him in perpetuity should not be done, unless there is a need
to do so.

So it would seem that according to R. Lior, as long as a child knows what they are doing, and the appointment of a child does not become the usual practice (absent some pressing communal need), there is no problem in having a child lead Qabbalath Shabbath once in a while.

I’d imagine אוצר בפני עצמו is a typo for אומר בפני עצמו

@JoelK could be... I wasn't sure if it was a niche use of rabbinic idiom... I see the phrase comes up in a couple of midrashim but not exactly used like this.
